# How do I give buttons colors

Tags: python, discord.py

Simple question, how do I make buttons in discord-components colored. e.g button 1 would be green and 2 would be red.

```
    await ctx.send(
        "Make You Choice",
        components = [
          [
            Button(label = "Bet Green", custom_id = "button1"),
            Button(label = "Bet Red", custom_id = "button2"),
            Button(label = "Bet Black", custom_id = "button3"),
        ],
          [          
            Button(label = "Bet 1,2,3,4", custom_id = "button4"),
            Button(label = "Bet 5,6,7,8", custom_id = "button5"),
            Button(label = "Bet 9,10,11,12", custom_id = "button6")
            ],
          [  
            Button(label = "Bet 13,14,15,16", custom_id = "button7"),
            Button(label = "Bet 17,18,19,20", custom_id = "button8"),
            Button(label = "Bet 21,22,23,24", custom_id = "button9")
        ],
           [
            Button(label = "Bet 25,26,27,28", custom_id = "button10"),
            Button(label = "Bet 29,30,31,32", custom_id = "button11"),
            Button(label = "Bet 33,34,35,36", custom_id = "button12")     
        ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [style](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#button-object-button-styles), e.g.

```
Button(label="Bet Green", style=2, custom_id="button1") # green button
# or 
Button(label="Bet Green", style='2', custom_id="button1") # green button
```

also in [discord-components docs](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/api-reference/component/button) and [Button Styles](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/api-reference/component/button/buttonstyle).
note, its unclear whether the value is `int` or `str`

Answer (score 1):

According to the DOCS -> https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#buttons

Buttons can be styled by setting the style parameter to a desired style(which you can see a list of on the docs page linked above).

For example)
Say you wanted one of your buttons to be green. You would simply change this line.

`Button(label = "Bet Green", custom_id = "button1")`

To something like this

`Button(label = "Bet Green", style = 3, custom_id = "button1")`